# Prevent double events in calendar

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Any ideas about prevent double events in calendar ? I have a button to insert a new event but don't want this if the event already exist!

This what I tryed

```
for (i=0; i<arrayofCalIDs.count; i++) {
                                      EKEvent* event2 = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:  [arrayofCalIDs    objectAtIndex:i]];

if (event2 == nil) {

 //here I add the event
}
```

Comment: to save the event identifier in an array and with a loop for check if the identifier already exist! But the identifier change every time i press my addEventButton so the loop never find it!

Comment: Per class ref, "If the calendar of an event changes, its identifier most likely changes as well." So it's not surprising that the event identifier isn't doing the trick. 
Superclass `EKCalendarItem` has a property `calendarItemIdentifier`, but it can be dumped upon sync. 
Maybe the `URL` property would be dependable?